# TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 20: 'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

парни! ломаю голову.
Нужно проверять условие и в зависимости от него выводить в том или ином виде иконку
Я проверяю сначала одну, затем другую и возникает ошибка.
Первое условие проверяется и все работает, но потом ловлю
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 20: 'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

строка 20 - это во втором блоке if/else/endif элемент else.
Есть какой-нибудь более элегантный способ сделать это?

```html
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    {% if e.eva_is_viber > 0 %}
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-viber fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fab fa-viber fa-2x" style="color: silver;"></i></li>
    {% endif %}
    { if e.eva_is_telegram > 0 % }
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-telegram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    {% else %}
    <p>no</p>
    { % endif % }
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: `{ if e.eva_is_telegram > 0 % }` — у Вас форматирование неправильное. Присмотритесь, в начале нет `%`, а в конце лишний пробел. Аналогично с `{ % endif % }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас ошибка в форматировании последних тегов `{% if %}` и `{% endif %}`.

***Замените на:***

```html
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    {% if e.eva_is_viber > 0 %}
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-viber fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fab fa-viber fa-2x" style="color: silver;"></i></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if e.eva_is_telegram > 0 %}
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-telegram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    {% else %}
    <p>no</p>
    {% endif %}
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
```